# Unbinding Masonry

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-masonry

**Scenario:**

I'm currently working with KnockoutJS, jQuery UI's sortable and Masonry. I use Knockout to display a list of cards, Masonry to arrange the cards properly, and sortable for sorting the cards.

The cards are of similar size, but I'll be introducing different sizes later on so I surely need Masonry to help me arrange them.

I'm using a customized bindingHandler function for the sortable so that when the user sorts the cards, the item's position gets updated in the knockout observableArray.

**Problem:**

Since the knockout sortable function removes the item from the last position and puts it back to a new position, Masonry messes up and somehow sortable also not functions properly. What I discovered was if I simply float left all the cards without using Masonry, sortable works fine.

I plan to undo Masonry at the start of the sortable, and put it back at the stop of the sortable. However I don't know how to unbind Masonry. Is there a way? Or at least a way to get it working.

**Here's a prototype of what I'm trying to do:**
http://jsbin.com/avujom/9/edit

Answer (score 0):

you could use masonry's [destroy](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#destroy) to remove masonry. so it removes the Masonry functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-initialized state. and you could create masonry element when you needed by `msnry = new Masonry( container );`. Also you could use [layout](http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html#layout) method.